# Can't find why my code crashes

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote this code to **compare between A and B  columns** and whenever I have similar values like **if the column A = B** then  **show A, B, and C in  E,F, and G** like in the picture below :

[image]

**This is the code I am using:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Comparatif_Release()
Dim t1, t2, c
Dim d As Object
Dim i&, j&, l&
Dim f As Worksheet
Range("e1:g110000").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Set f = Sheets("Sheet1")
With f

    t1 = .Range("a1:a10000").Value
    t2 = .Range("b1:c10000").Value
End With

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For i = LBound(t1) To UBound(t1)
For j = LBound(t2) To UBound(t2)
    If t1(i, 1) = t2(j, 1) Then
        d(t1(i, 1) & ":" & t2(j, 1) & ":" & t2(j, 2)) = d(t1(i, 1) & ":" & t2(j, 1) & ":" & t2(j, 2))

    End If
Next j
Next i

With f
    i = 1
    For Each c In d.Keys
        .Cells(i, "E").Resize(, 3).Value = Split(c, ":")

        i = i + 1
    Next c
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Where does the problem occur?

Comment: the code crash and blocks , i need to restar excel  for me it should work , but no

Comment: Do you have data till row 10000?

Comment: If no then replace `t1 = .Range("a1:a10000").Value` to `t1 = .Range("a1:a" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value` and `t2 = .Range("b1:c10000").Value` to `t2 = .Range("b1:c" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Value`

Comment: this was it , thanks Mrig , it works now

Comment: Why don't you just write the values directly when you find a match? i.e. in the `If t1(i, 1) = t2(j, 1) Then` scope do `f.Cells(k, "E").Resize(, 3).Value = Array(t1(i,1),t2(j,1),t2(j,2)) : k=k+1`

Comment: yes its another way to show results bouth of your solutions works thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Use these formula and just filter them down.  It should work.  Late post, but just in case.

```
In column E1 :  =IF(A1=B1,A1,"")
In column F1 :  =IF(E1<>"",B1,"")
In Column G1 :  =If(E1<>"",C1,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple VBA version would be:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long
lastrow = Sheet1.Range("a1048575").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastrow
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 2) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) Then
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 4) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 5) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 6) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this part when you say then `d()=d()` ?
Where both keys are seemingly the same and might not exist?

Full quote is:

```
If t1(i, 1) = t2(j, 1) Then d(t1(i, 1) & ":" & t2(j, 1) & ":" & t2(j, 2)) = d(t1(i, 1) & ":" & t2(j, 1) & ":" & t2(j, 2))
```